# null is written to the Postman environment variable

Tags: json, null

I want to get the rating_id from the Json response and write it to an environment variable. But when sending a request, the "null" value is always written to the variable

**json request:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "rating_id": "{{$guid}}",
    "collection_id": "7a313397-00de-49f5-bfb7-6341323ac053",
    "rating": "1",
    "user_comment": "test",
    "status": "1",
    "create_date": "2023-03-01 11:05:00+03",
    "create_user": "ivanov.ii"
  }
}
```

**json response:**

```
{
    "state": "success",
    "data": {
        "rating_id": "67e5b082-1c35-434f-b5e1-96eaf60310ea",
        "collection_id": "7a313397-00de-49f5-bfb7-6341323ac053",
        "rating": "1",
        "user_comment": "test",
        "status": "1",
        "create_date": "2023-03-01T16:51:00.087477Z",
        "create_user": "ivanov.ii"
    }
}
```

**Tests:**

var jsonResponse = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set("rating_id", jsonResponse.rating_id);

Answer (score 0):

the problem was because "rating_id" was inside "date":

```
var jsonrespons = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set("rating_id", jsonrespons["data"]["rating_id"]);
```